# Access child iFrame DOM from parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

Here is the deal:

domain.com/page -- Parent page (document.domain=domain.com) contains an iframe
sub.domain.com/page -- Child iframe (document.domain=not set) is on a subdomain

Is there any way to access the DOM of that iframe or am I out of luck?

Does same origin policy block me from forcing a document.domain on an iframe contained within a parent page? I suppose that would defeat the purpose of the same origin policy... If that is the case, is there any workaround to access the DOM of the iframe on the rendered parent page?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a way.  When the page in the iframe loads, have it do the following

```
parent.childGetElementById = function (id) {return document.getElementById(id);}
parent.childLoaded();
```

This will make a function in the global scope of the parent page (that contains the iframe). Then in the parent, just have the following

```
function childLoaded() {var dom = childGetElementById('someid');}
```

This is along as you have control of the page your loading into the iframe... if you do not, you are out of luck.

Comment: I don't have access to the page loaded in the iframe, but this answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: Just wanted to clarify that this is impossible unless you have edit access to the iframe that you want to talk to.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for sharing with us. +1

Comment: Looks like this only works when you're on the same domain.

Comment: That is correct, otherwise it would be a security nightmare

Answer (score 10):

This is a browser security measure, otherwise everybody would be wrapping your banking websites and skimming off your passwords when you logged in.

You can talk from the iframe to the parent, but not back into an iframe again.

Comment: you can if it is under same domain

window.frames[0].document.getelementbyID("IdOfelementWithinIframe")

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck, as far as I know. You can talk between them using the hash-bang in the URL though, see [this](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) for a decent discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the pages are third party and I don't have access to them like this