# Access Child iframe elements from parent page with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

How can i access the elements of a child div within a Jquery UI Dialog from a parent page? I Was using the following code.. though accessing the iframe with its id ( #adduserframe ) and then .contents() will do the work.. but it is not working.. my jquery concepts are not good enough. Can anyone suggest what shall bring me my desired results? Can you plz tell why i am being unable to get the elements?

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var first_name = '';
            var middle_name = ''; 
            var last_name = '';
            var paginate_url='';
            $('#first_name,#middle_name,#last_name').bind( "change" ,function(){
                first_name = $.trim($('#first_name').val());
                middle_name = $.trim($('#middle_name').val()); 
                last_name = $.trim($('#last_name').val());
                paginate_url='autosuggestUsers.php?first_name=' + first_name + '&middle_name=' + middle_name + '&last_name=' + last_name;
                if( first_name!='' && middle_name!='' && last_name!='' ){

                    $('<div><iframe id="adduserframe" src="'+ paginate_url + '" height="300" width="478" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>').dialog({
                        title: '<b>User(s) with a similar name</b>',
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen: true,
                        height: 'auto',
                        width: 500,
                        resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            "Close": function(){                    
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }); 

            $("#adduserframe").contents().find("img.addSweis").live("click",function(){
                alert('hey');
                var u_data = $(this).attr('rel');
                var rawParts = u_data.split("~~^^~~");
                $($("#adduserframe").contents().find("input#relative_id")).val(rawParts[0]);
                $($("#adduserframe").contents().find("input#first_name")).val(rawParts[1]);

                $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('close');
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See : Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page)

But it will only work if all the scripts and iframe are on the same domain.

Comment: They are on same domain.. Thank you!

Comment: so you can access it using `$("#adduserframe").contents()`, is it returning an object at all?

Comment: I don't know. What can i use to see if it is returning one or not? However the simple alert is not working.. so i don't think it is working at all..

Comment: just do `alert('$("#adduserframe").contents()');` if it returns null then I think your iframe doesn't exist in the dom yet and you are trying to access it

Comment: is there any HTML that goes with this?

Comment: It is a php page and html contents are being generated by using the parameters in the query string.
autosuggestUsers.php?first_name=' + first_name + '&middle_name=' + middle_name + '&last_name=' + last_name