# Iframe inside Iframe cant do changes

Tags: javascript

I have one iframe inside on iframe and with this code i want to change the src of an image

```
window.top.frames[0].frames[0].document.getElementById("maquina").src = "https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png";
```

and when i try it it work but i cant see changes in the page, only in code when e read .src
of that element

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate the contents of an iframe from within the parent frame without a global method for accessing the child DOM. There is an answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page) that suits your needs, but I will copy below for reference:

In the child iframe:

```
parent.childGetElementById = function (id) {return document.getElementById(id);}
parent.childLoaded();
```

In the parent:

```
function childLoaded() {var dom = childGetElementById('someid');}
```

Assuming you actually have access to the child page, I would recommend modifying your design away from the use of iframes.

*[Answering the comment]*

Well it depends on if you're just using straight HTML, or a scripting language (like PHP). If pure HTML, you can use a server side includes with

```
<!-- #include virtual="path/to/included/file.html" -->
```

In PHP, you can include the page like this

```
require('/real/path/to/included/file.php');
```

Don't get me wrong, iFrames can be useful in some specific situations (circumventing cross-domain origin policies, oAuth implementations, etc); they are more often abused than correctly used.

Comment: ok i will try that, but what the best method to create "modules" of html without iframes?