# How to make an html id defined in an html accessable in another html file

Tags: html

How can I let an id that is defined in an html or jsp file be accessable in another file?

The reason for doing this is that I used Ajax to get some content that is defined in another file. And I want the id of that content to be accessable from my first file.

I tried to look for a way to change the scope of the id but couldn't find.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"access[i]ble"_? *How* do you want to access content marked with an id from another document?

Comment: If you use AJAX that other file becomes part of your first file so will be accessible in the same way. Or do I not understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't.
But you could create an iframe from your html page and load the file that you want to access. either make the iframe hidden or of no size.

Here is a post that mentions how to do access id's like that:

[Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page)