# Implementing JS script for iframe on another domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

I have the following code for an iframe of a page from my site which includes a script that resizes the height of the iframe based on the height of the content. As is, the code works on my site without any issues, but i need to implement this iframe plus the javascript on another domain. right now it does not work i presume because of cross domain security. What code do I need to implement on my end or/and in the code i implement on the other domain to get the javascript to work?
The Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function autosizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}</script>
<iframe id="autoheight" src="http://fourleagues.com/monumental" width="620" height="300" 
frameborder="no" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:autosizeIframe(this);'></iframe>
```

Comment: You could utilize server-side code to proxy the request.  But I'm not sure if this is an option for you.

Comment: I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page