# How do to add HTML elements in front when using A-Frame

Tags: javascript, frame

When you add HTML elements to a basic scene running the framework A-Frame, the elements are hidden by the scene created by A-Frame. The scene covers the whole viewport and every other element. I want some usual 2D GUI elements at the front to control the scene.
I had no success with using the css z-index.

**How do I control the rendering order of the HTML elements im my DOM?**

Possible solution involves using an iFrame for the A-Frame scene and this hack to access the DOM of the iFrame:
[Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page)

This sound a bit too complicated for such a simple task.