# How can we access child Iframe from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to find the alert inside the child I frame from the parent.

And inside I frame i am keeping the another web page which i don't have access on it so i cant get the alert displayed inside I Frame.

So,how to find the alert message inside *I frame* from Parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page)

Comment: Yes, Post message i tried it worked so Iframe domain is not going to post the message now to window ,so any other way to capture the alert inside the IFrame ?@WillJenkins

Comment: the I Frame URL is coming from different Domain so i cant get the id of those ...will it work ?@FrozenButcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The contents of an `iframe` cannot be accessed if the parent and child are served from different domains. If they could, it would be possible to wrap any 3rd party page and capture passwords etc from it.

The only way to communicate cross-domain requires you to have control of the iframe contents. If you can add a script then you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send events etc in both directions.

Comment: or it is possible to postMessage from Backend to UI ?

Comment: @RaviG postMessage communicates between windows / tabs, not the client and the server. Using postMessage needs _both_ parties to participate.